# PHP fail to move file from temp folder to specified folder

Tags: php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "func.php";
connectToDatabase("localhost","root","","test");
$fileName = $_FILES['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['type'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['temp_name'];
$uploaderID = $_SESSION['id'];
$date = date("d/m-Y");
$uploadDir = "avatarStor/";
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

if(!$fileName){
    echo "Error: value 'fileName' was undefined<br>";
}

$result = move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $filePath);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Error: File could not be uploadet: ".$fileName;
    exit;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profilepicture='$fileName' WHERE id='$uploaderID'") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

I am unable to `move_uploaded_file();` in this uploading script. I went ahead and `chmod 777` the folder, but nevertheless, it failed. PHP provides no errors when running.
[image: Result]

Comment: Also, seems to be not a reliable date format `date("d/m-Y");`.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` to become more educated what you deal here with. Also you can consider to  do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: Like for `$_SESSION` there exists a PHP manual page, too, for `$_FILES`. Start to use the existing resources: http://de3.php.net/$_FILES .

Comment: The debugging gave me all the correct information such as name filesize etc. and no errors were found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 
`$fileTempName = $_FILES['temp_name'];` 
to 
`$fileTempName = $_FILES['that_input_name']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Is it exactly ['that_input_name'] ?

Comment: No. It's the name of the input you're using. For example, there's `<input type="file" name="junk">` in your form, it will be `$_FILES['junk']['tmp_name']`

Comment: I tried
$fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['temp_name'];
It didn't work and the name of my input:
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

Comment: Read carefuly - it's `tmp_name`, not `temp_name`.

Comment: Both 'tmp_name' and 'temp_name' give the same string

Comment: What? $_FILES should not have any `temp_name` index. Read the manual.